# Двоеточие или всё же тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, двоеточие, тире-или-двоеточие

"Всем стало ясно: взошла новая звезда".

Answer (score 2):

Можно рекомендовать двоеточие. Постановку этого знака аргументировать несложно: два простых предложения в составе сложного не соединены поредством союзов, при этом в первом предложении посредством семанически неполноценного слова *ясно* делается предупреждение, что далее последует изложение какого-нибудь факта. Следует при этом иметь в виду, что в практике письма последних десятилетий (особенно в публицистической речи) широко проявляется тенденция заменять в таких случаях двоеточие на тире. Однако же строгой нормой, рекомендуемой наиболее авторитетными грамматиками, по сей день остаётся двоеточие.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, двоеточие: второе предложение раскрывает смысл первого.

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь, это не тот случай, хотя и схожий. Второе предложение здесь не может раскрывать содержание первого именно в силу семантической неполноты слова *ясно*. Попробуйте вставить между частями сложного предложения *а именно* – и поймёте свою ошибку. :)

Answer (score 0):

При дополнении вставляется союз "что", а не союз "а именно".

Comment: Вы неправы, здесь для проверки нужно вставлять союз *а именно*. См. об этом у Розенталя параграф "Двоеточие в бессоюзном сложном предложении". При желании можно подставлять союз *потому что* или *то есть*. Но никак не *что*, у него совершенно иная семантика. Кстати, что вы понимаете под *дополнением*? Если член предложения, то я в недоумении. (Ох, сколько слов на -ение...) :)